# Devenv ProjectConfig switch - Win32 and x64

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Running Visual Studio 2008 interactively, I can build the project successfully for both the x64 and Win32 targets.  However, if I invoke devenv, regardless of my /projectconfig argument, it always performs the x64 build:

```
devenv /Rebuild Release MySolution.sln /projectconfig "Release|Win32"

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.21022.8.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
------ Rebuild All started: Project: my-project, Configuration: Release x64 ------
```

Note that the /projectconfig arg doesn't match the Configuration: output.  Am I missing something simple?  It works fine within the IDE but there are a bunch of targets and I'd prefer to script it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening, but does it work with the following?

```
devenv /Rebuild "Release|Win32" MySolution.sln
```

Or alternatively, using `msbuild`:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32 /t:proj:Rebuild
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah, both of those work, except proj can't be an action, like "Rebuild" (so it works with just /t:rebuild).  And actually, I've never used msbuild but I already like it much more than devenv.  Thanks twice!

Comment: The syntax for which targets can be used with msbuild is a bit undiscoverable, but you should find it leaves behind a file `mysolution.sln.cache` -- this is msbuild's own project file. In there you'll find a list of the target names it generates for your project. There's an overall 'Rebuild' target but also a per-project one 'proj:Rebuild'.  Another benefit of msbuild is that if you upgrade to VS2010 then you'll get the better parallel building for free.

Comment: Yeah, I did finally notice that I could specify a single project, but I was trying to rebuild all of them anyway.  I also encountered memory issues when I used the multi-threaded build feature, but I'm stuck on VS2008 for now, and using a single CPU seems to work ok.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2019 to build .NET 5 solution with devenv.exe in command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com SolutionName.sln /build "Release|x86" /project Project /projectconfig Release
```

Still did not affect on build configuration and used **Any CPU** instead of **x86**:

```
14:08:42      [exec] 80>------ Build started: Project: Project, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
```

After dig into Project.csproj (note this is **.NET 5** project file format) file I found this:

```
<Platforms>AnyCPU;x86;x64</Platforms>
```

Experimentally changed platforms order to:

```
<Platforms>x86;AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
```

And it did the trick:

```
15:27:30      [exec] 80>------ Build started: Project: Project, Configuration: Release x86 ------
```

Hope this helps someone who uses devenv.com for assembling nowadays.